# How can I catch an event generated by a child in a parent control?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have created a listbox control and I redefined the style of the ListBoxItem as follows:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type customControls:CheckedListBox}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Expander x:Name="PART_Expander" IsExpanded="True">
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple"/>
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Name="PART_ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Selector.IsSelected="True" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Content="{Binding Path=.}">
                            </CheckBox>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

In the code behind of the CheckedListBox I raise an event when any Checkboxes are clicked:

```
       protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
            RaiseRefreshDataEvent(e.RemovedItems);
        }
        protected virtual void RaiseRefreshDataEvent(IList changedItems)
        {
            RefreshDataSetEventArgs args = new RefreshDataSetEventArgs(CheckedListBox.RefreshDataSetEvent, changedItems);
            RaiseEvent(args);
        }
        public static readonly RoutedEvent RefreshDataSetEvent =
    EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("RefreshDataSet", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
    typeof(RefreshDataSetEventHandler), typeof(CheckedListBox));

        public event RefreshDataSetEventHandler RefreshDataSet
        {
            add { AddHandler(RefreshDataSetEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(RefreshDataSetEvent, value); }
        }


        public delegate void RefreshDataSetEventHandler(Object sender, RefreshDataSetEventArgs e);
 public class RefreshDataSetEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
        {
            public IList ValueChanged { get; set; }
            public RefreshDataSetEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent, IList valuesChanged) : base(routedEvent)
            {
                ValueChanged = valuesChanged;
            }
        }
```

Now, I want to catch the RefreshDataSetEvent in one of the parents of the CheckedListBox.
I've been able to do this by going through the visual tree objects, finding the CheckedListBox and adding a method from the parent class to the object using RefreshDataSet.
This *seems* like a hack to me.  I would expect that if the event is truly bubbling up the visual tree, I *should* be able to catch it without having to explicitly add a handler to the source object.
Any idea how I can catch this event without explicitly setting the handler on the object?

## EDIT

The CheckBoxList is used within another custom control called FilterDataGrid (which is the class I'd like to handle the event).  Here's the style for the FilterDataGrid:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type customControls:FilterDataGrid}"
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Name="PART_DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <customControls:CheckedListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

So, when I try to add customControls:CheckedListBox.RefreshDataSet="TestThis" to the Style, I get an error saying to use an EventSetter.
When I add the following to the style for an event setter I get an "Unknown build error, Object reference not set to an instance of an object":
        
            
        
According to the docs, you can't use an eventsetter in a Generic.xaml file.  Or at least that's what I glean from:

> Event setters cannot be used in a style that is contained in a theme
>   resource dictionary. This is because a theme resource dictionary at
>   run time is often loose binary XAML (BAML) files, and does not have
>   any scope defined where accompanying code-behind that defines the
>   handlers can exist.

So I'm wondering how I go about setting the Eventhandler if I can't specify it in the Themes/Generic.xaml file.

Comment: If the event is bubbling up, just put a handler on any ancestor. `<Grid local:CheckedListBox.RefreshDataSet="Grid_RefreshDataSet" >...`

Comment: @EdPlunkett I seem to be running into an error when doing that on the custom control which uses the CheckedListBox.  I've edited the question to give a little more information.

Comment: I'd really hate to advise you to do it in the C# code for `FilterDataGrid`, in the constructor or somewhere. But that's an option.

Comment: Oh, better (OK, less awful) option: You could write an attached property/behavior which does it, the apply the attached property in the theme. I believe the XAML designer isn't smart enough to theme-police you for that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Alright, I'll give it a shot and let you know how it goes.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by Registering a class handler in the EventManager.
In the public constructor for the FilterDataGrid class, put the following code:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(FilterDataGrid), CheckedListBox.RefreshDataSetEvent, new CheckedListBox.RefreshDataSetEventHandler(FilterDataGridRefreshEventHandler));
```

Considering both FilterDataGrid and CheckedListBox are custom controls, I figured putting a hard link between the two was ok (feel free to let me know of the potential pitfalls, I'm still rather new to this control authoring thing).